# How can i display the Exact Same Colors that are in the Texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

I would like to render an animated prism, i made a texture with a different color for each face and some text. I want it to render it with no lighting, just the exact same texture, pixel to pixel as a transparent png sequence. They are simple bright folors like FF00FF and FF000. I just want it to be as flat as possible, with the exact same pixel values as the texture. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just connect your image texture directly to the material output without using a shader first. In the image below, the cube on the left is connected directly, and the one on the right is connected through a Principled BSDF with default settings. The light is directly between them.

[image: NoShader]

Comment: Color management settings should probably also be considered.